# How to create a combo modal in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I need it when searching for an item in the combo, the entire component, both the search and the results list are a modal. If you use:

```
listConfig:{
    modal: true
}
```

Only the list of results gets modal, and using modal: true in combo nothing happens, does anyone have any solution? I will use this for a general search field in my system, where when searching I want it to become modal as it is the main search of the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add listeners on combo:

```
listeners: {
    expand: 'expandSearchFilter',
    collapse:'colapseSearchFilter'
}
```

And on controller:

```
expandSearchFilter :function ( me , eOpts) {
    Ext.getBody().mask();
},
colapseSearchFilter:function ( me , eOpts) {
    Ext.getBody().unmask();
}
```